# Unnecessary nodes generation in firebase database using Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, chat

I am creating a real time chatting application using Android Studio.

Here's my Adapter for chatting implementation.

```
package com.example.chatbox.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.chatbox.R
import com.example.chatbox.models.Message
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class ChatAdapter(private val list: ArrayList<Message>, val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    class SentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val sentMsg = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sent_msg)!!
        val sentTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sent_time)!!
    }

    class ReceivedViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val receivedMsg = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.received_msg)!!
        val receivedTime = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.received_time)!!
    }

    // 1 -> Use sender viewHolder
    // 2 -> Use receiver viewHolder
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (list[position].senderID == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
            1
        else
            0
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == 1)
            SentViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_sent, parent, false)
            )
        else
            ReceivedViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_received, parent, false)
            )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val temp = list[position]

        if (holder.itemViewType == 1) {
            (holder as SentViewHolder).sentMsg.text = temp.msg
            holder.sentTime.text = temp.time
        }
        else {
            (holder as ReceivedViewHolder).receivedMsg.text = temp.msg
            holder.receivedTime.text = temp.time

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

This is the code for chatting Activity.

```
package com.example.chatbox

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.chatbox.adapters.ChatAdapter
import com.example.chatbox.models.Message
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        val senderId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val receiverId = intent.getStringExtra("uid").toString()
        val receiverName = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val receiverProfile = intent.getStringExtra("profile")

        val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.chat_user_name)
        val profile = findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.chat_profile)

        name.text = receiverName
        Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(receiverProfile))
            .into(profile)

        findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.chat_back).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        }

        val list = ArrayList<Message>()
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView1)
        val adapter = ChatAdapter(list, this)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val edtChat = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.chat_msg_edt)
        val btnSend = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.chat_send)

        // ID Database for sender
        val senderDBID = "Sender : $senderId  Receiver : $receiverId"
        // ID Database for receiver
        val receiverDBID = "Sender : $receiverId  Receiver : $senderId"

        // TextWatcher to avoid empty message
        edtChat.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                // enable send button only when message is not empty
                if (s.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()) {
                    btnSend.setImageResource(R.drawable.send)

                } else if (s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    btnSend.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone)
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }
        })

        btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            val msg = edtChat.text.toString()

            val model = Message()
            model.msg = msg
            model.time = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(Date()).toString()
            model.senderID = senderId.toString()

            // push the messages to both sender's and receiver's database
            Firebase.database.reference.child("Chats")
                // Sender's chat will be saved here
                .child(senderId+receiverId)
                .push()
                .setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener {
                    Firebase.database.reference.child("Chats")
                        // Receiver's chat will be saved here
                        .child(receiverId+senderId)
                        .push()
                        .setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener {
                        }
                }
            edtChat.setText(getString(R.string.empty_string))
        }

        // Reading from database
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(senderId+receiverId)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    list.clear()
                    for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                        val model: Message = snap.getValue(Message::class.java)!!
                        list.add(model)
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
    }

}
```

Message Class

```
package com.example.chatbox.models

class Message {
    var senderID:String = ""
    var msg:String = ""
    var time:String = ""
}
```

Above code works fine and messages are sent and received properly. Only two nodes are created in firebase database one for sender and one for receiver chat, which is fine.

Here starts the issue.
In case you did not notice below variables were not used.

```
// ID Database for sender
val senderDBID = "Sender : $senderId  Receiver : $receiverId"
// ID Database for receiver
val receiverDBID = "Sender : $receiverId  Receiver : $senderId"
```

In the ChatActivity, while pushing messages to database if senderId + receiverId is replaced by senderDBID and receiverId + senderId is replaced by receiverDBID then

1. The sending works fine and ne sent messages are displayed in the chat.
2. But received messages do not appear in the chat but are pushed to firebase.
3. Also Four nodes are created for a P2P chat named

   - Sender : ID1 Receiver : ID2
   - Receiver : ID2 Sender : ID1
   - Sender : ID2 Receiver : ID1
   - Receiver : ID1 Sender : ID2

I've observed the code multiple times, but I can not understand that how changing name of path in firebase could change the working of my code.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Code Link : [Click Here.](https://github.com/alph-a07/Android-App-Development/tree/master/ChatBox)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Code link added.